# logic to write the function find_maximum_people

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Consider that the human tower is to be performed on a stage and the stage has a maximum weight limit.
Write a python program to find the maximum number of people at the base level such that the total weight of tower does not exceed the maximum weight limit of the stage.
Assume that:

1. Each person weighs 50 kg.
2. There will always be odd number of men at the base level of the human tower.
3. At each level number of people reduces by 2.

   ```
   def human_pyramid(no_of_people):
       if (no_of_people == 1):
       return 1 * (50)
       else:
           return no_of_people * (50) + human_pyramid(no_of_people - 2)

   def find_maximum_people(max_weight):
       pass

   max_people = find_maximum_people(1000)
   print(max_people)
   ```

Comment: Can you provide with expected output things?

Comment: Have you tried solving your homework yourself yet? What went wrong?

Comment: actually its a problem in the assignment so i dont have any outputs

Comment: @Selcuk yes  i could not get the approach how to solve, Code is not necessary only logic would work

Comment: The maximum number of people on the base is just the first odd number under the maximum amount of people? (1000 / 50 = 20) => answer is 19. There is no requirement for a tower to actually be made?

Comment: Well, since it doesn't say that there must be a single person at the top, I would say `int(max_weight / 50)` or the nearest smaller odd number. Edit: Beaten by @IainShelvington

Comment: If the problem statement is incomplete, and there must be a single person at the top, then start with 1 and keep adding odd numbers (3, 5, 7, etc) until the total is `max_weight`. You can also use Gauss' method to find the sum of odd numbers from 1 to n.

Comment: @Selcuk your advice worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #this funtion return the weight of the tower  
    def human_pyramid(no_of_people): 
        if (no_of_people == 1):
            return 1 * (50)
        else:
            return no_of_people * (50) + human_pyramid(no_of_people - 2)

    def find_maximum_people(max_weight):
        i=1
        while i<(max_weight//50):
            current_weight=human_pyramid(i)
            if current_weight>max_weight:
                return i-1 
                #when the weight exceed this means older value was in the limit
            i=i+2
    max_people = find_maximum_people(1000)
    print(max_people)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def human_pyramid(no_of_people): 
    if (no_of_people == 1):
        return 1 * (50)
    else:
        return no_of_people * (50) + human_pyramid(no_of_people - 2)

def find_maximum_people(max_weight):
    max=max_weight//50
    i = max
    while i<=max:            
        curr=human_pyramid(max)
        max=max-2
        i=i-2
max_people = find_maximum_people(1000)
print(max_people)
```